# LibGDX 3d mesh transformation

Tags: java, 3d, libgdx

my intention is to make the "liquid" 3d structure, which is dynamically changing. The idea is to make it as the array of meshes and then change the elevation of the points of meshes.

So, my question is how to transform the mesh by setting the vertices Y variable? And is it even possible in LibGDX?

Comment: See https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/g3d/HeightMapTest.java for an example. See the top of https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/g3d/HeightField.java for the documentation on how to use it. You can dynamically modify the `data` and then call `update` to update the mesh.